# К чему обращаться внутри класса, если есть приватное поле и публичное свойство, ссылающееся на это поле?

Tags: c#

Допустим, у нас есть поле, и ссылающееся на него свойство.

```
public int I =>_i;
private int _i;
```

Понятно, что все внешние классы будут ссылаться на свойство, т.к. оно публичное.
А внутри этого класса? Доступ есть и к свойству, и к полю, и они идентичны. Логики никакой дополнительной не навешано, это просто геттер.

На что ссылаться при обращении внутри класса? на публичное свойство или приватное поле? Как правильнее? Может есть от msdn какое-то правило?

Comment: Вы ведь сами себе ответили на вопрос `это просто геттер`, то есть вы не можете сделать `I = 1;`, ибо `I` в вашем случае доступен "только для чтения", соответственно, как вы собираетесь ему задать значение?

Comment: Наверное, логично было бы всё же читать/писать приватное поле для единообразия. А то как-то странно было бы писать в поле, а читать геттер в одном и том же месте кода. Кстати, вы потеряли `_` в названии поля, я так понимаю.

Comment: @CrazyElf Добавил название поля, спасибо.

Comment: Даже, если сейчас у Вас нет логики в геттере свойства, в дальнейшем она может появиться, поэтому, имхо, лучше везде используйте геттер.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не понимаете, для чего нужны свойства. Смотрите, если у вас в классе есть переменная, которая используется внутри этого класса, то смысла делать свойство нет, достаточно приватного поля. Если у вас эта переменная используется за пределами класса, то лучше использовать свойство и закрывать доступ к чтению/записи. Ваш код, к примеру лучше было бы написать, как `public int I {get; private set;}`, тогда и доступ есть везде и записать можете только внутри класса. Также не забываем про логику, которую можно написать в `get/set`, в этом случае использовать нужно только свойство!

Comment: Мне кажется, данный вопрос следует разбирать не на этом вымышленном и имеющим мало чего общего с реальностью кусочке кода, а на нормальном рабочем коде. Берем целый класс, сначала дизайним его одним способом, потом вторым, а уже только потом разбираем и сравниваем реализации. Ваш вопрос имеет очень слабый теоретический ответ, и достаточно сильный практический. И если у вас один геттер, вы забыли про метод `public int GetI()`. В некоторых случаях публикация данных делается, не через поле, и не через свойство, а через метод. Так что выбирать надо именно из трех.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это стилистический вопрос, и решать его надо лично вам. Подумайте, какую логику вы хотите передать вашим кодом.

Если вы хотите подчеркнуть логику «это то самое значение, которое видно снаружи», то логичнее было бы обращаться через свойство. Если вы хотите подчеркнуть логику «это то поле, которое является источником значения», то обращайтесь через поле.

Возможно, вам поможет следующее соображение. Подумайте, что будет, если бы ваш код выглядел так: `public int I => _i + 1;` — вы бы при этих условиях обращались к полю, или к свойству?

В любом случае, поскольку ваше поле правильно инкапсулировано, нет ничего страшного, если вы выберете не тот из двух вариантов: ведь можно всегда переделать, не ломая внешний код, раз поле приватное. (Вот если бы вы по ошибке сделали поле публичным, вот тогда могли бы быть проблемы.) Если нет никакого очевидного предпочтения в случае, который у вас вызывает вопросы, пишите как вам вздумается.